# What is the song when Obito attacked Naruto and Sasuke in episode 378 of "Naruto Shippuden"?

Tags: naruto, music

Which song was played in Naruto Shippuden episode 378 at about 15:10, when Obito attacked Naruto and Sasuke?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a clip taken out of "Shouryuu"  or "Rising Dragon" starting at about 0:30 into the OST.

It is from Naruto Shippuden OST 2 and is Track 1.

Source: [Naruto Music on Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music)

Comment: No buddy its not it, but thnx for trying

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this track from the Madara vs the Shinobi Alliance fight.

It looks like this one wasn't released in any of the official OST soundtracks. It doesn't appear in any of the tracks [in this list](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music#Original_Soundtracks) (as of 2018).

There are some unofficial versions online, although they are low quality because of the limited sample size. For example, there's one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViXvVpJh5Ts), titled "Fighting Akatsuki" by the uploader.